# How to Auto-populate an SharePoint 2013 Form Based on SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath

I am trying to get ahead of the end of InfoPath. I have several InfoPath forms that auto-populate data from SharePoint lists based on the User entering a numeric unique ID.

I've created a SharePoint form based on one of the lists. All of the list columns appear; I now need to be able to allow the User to enter the unique ID, which would them trigger the auto-population of all the other fields.

Is the above possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Rules** to set field's value on InfoPath form.
[Set a field’s value](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-rules-for-performing-other-actions-5322d726-b787-4e5f-8d37-ba6db68b451d#__toc269451425)
[SharePoint 2010 InfoPath Forms and Rules](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/405406/SharePoint-2010-InfoPath-Forms-and-Rules)